# Ajax form submission with not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, validation, jquery

So here's my fiddle i've been working on : http://jsfiddle.net/DW3UM/2/

```
.highlight {border:1px solid #4f67f5;color:red;}
.res-msg-wr {display:none;}
```

This is ( as you can see) a contact form , and I think I've done everything right to make it work... But somehow it doesn't work the right way...

(1) The validation doesn't not work... Though I've almost copied the code but it should work.. Though it doesn't

(2) The process.php File Doesn't work even (irony) .. The same contact form works on my other site... But I'm trying to incorporate it in a new one... and it surprisingly doesn't seem to function the right way... If I put the values in the form it doesn't load up the success message.. and if I leave one of the fields empty and fill one of the inputs.. It still shows the error message regarding every input..I've provided everything in the fiddle...  Any help would be much appreciated ...

Comment: Where do you want the validation to take place, front end or the PHP?  BTW, I'd suggest removing the PHP part of this question into a separate question. You haven't shown the php so there's no way to know how its validation isn't working.

Comment: I included it in the fiddle.. sorry .. Im just a newbie

Comment: Here's the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/DW3UM/3/

Comment: I want the validation to take place on th client side first...and if he bypasses it somehow... then as a security raeson on the server side

Comment: We were all newbies once. If you're not using the native submit functionality of a form (i.e. you're doing it in JavaScript) then you'll get problems using a form and it's submit button (it's going to do submit regardless of your JavaScript). Try using a normal button instead. You can get rid of the form concept from the HTML.

Comment: So do i need to get rid of the js validation?

Comment: I personally would do the validation in JS, not php, it's faster. I know I'm not supposed to reference sites, but kronia.com.au has a pretty basic 'form' on the front page and plain javascript that you can look at. It checks that the forms are filled out correctly, show messages if they're not, and sends of the AJAX if validation passes.

Comment: OK i saw it..Its good... But the AJAX submission is a bit tricky...know any sources for tutorials ? Coz i need to do the AJAX submission

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DW3UM/4/

Comment: its honestly good to do validation in both .. especially if its a security risk.  you dont want someone turning off their JS and submitting the form with nasty stuff

Comment: @hamobi good point. Your PHP should use PDO and bindParam before sending any SQL to the database. majid w3schools is good for beginners but MDN is the best https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 1):

This

```
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Doesn't Work. `$.noConflict();` removes the `$` alias for the jQuery object so it can't be used to bind to the ready event.

Either remove the noConflict call or replace all instance of `$` with `jQuery`

Also make sure all of your inputs have a name attribute. In the fiddle they where missing.

Comment: @Majid you are not including jquery on your fiddle

Comment: @Majid add name attributes to the input elements. answer updated

Answer (score 0):

return false does the following:

event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Also:
The first variable in your url for the GET request should begin with ? not &
'&name=' should be '?name='

Your fiddle does not appear to be including the jQuery library.

Comment: Can you post the mended code ... Please.. Coz I'm still a newbie to js.. and php... Btw here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DW3UM/4/